# Switch from Google Analytics to Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have site which run on Google Analytics for some time( more than 1 year), now I want to use Google Tag Manager. If i remove Google Analytics from site, and start tracking with tag manager, there is a risk of losing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to give a helpful answer to that - if you manage a seamless switch between GTM and inline GA code, and have set up everything correctly  then you will not lose data. Is there a risk you make mistakes ? Probably.

I recommend  to integrate GTM alongside GA and set up your GA tags so that they track to a test property. Then you can compare both properties to make sure that you track actually the same things. And that point you can throw out the inline GA code and switch to GTM (if you implement the tracking id as a variable in GTM it will be as simple as changing a single variable).

But remember to actually remove the inline code, else you will end up with double pageviews.

Comment: And while I am adding GTM i can have 2 different GA connected to one site?

Comment: Yes, as long as they use different tracking ids (if you use the same id you will have doublecounting).

Comment: Thank you very much for help